# Differentiation wrt matrix involvoing Khatri-rao product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I got a following minimization problem

$$\min_{\mathbf{X}^{(1)}, \, \mathbf{X}^{(2)}} \;\left\| \mathbf{B} - \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{X}^{(1)} \odot \mathbf{X}^{(2)}) \right\|^{2}_{F},$$

where the matrices $\mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times 3}$, $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{100\times 36}$, $\mathbf{X}^{(1)}\in \mathbb{R}^{9 \times 3}$ and $\mathbf{X}^{(2)}\in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 3}$. The operation $\odot$ refers to the [Khatri-rao product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Khatri.E2.80.93Rao_product).

Given matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, my problem is to find out matrices $\mathbf{X}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{X}^{(2)}$  such that

$$\mathbb{f} = \left\| \mathbf{B} - \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{X}^{(1)} \odot \mathbf{X}^{(2)}) \right\|^{2}_{F}$$

is minimized.

My idea is to compute the gradient of $\mathbb{f}$ with respect to $\mathbf{X}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{X}^{(2)}$ respectively.

My question is, how to do differentiation with respect to a matrix? I have consulted a [reference](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf) but the situation seems different because it involves a Khatri-rao product in $\mathbb{f}$. Thanks in advance.

$\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}^{(1)}}$ and $\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}^{(2)}} $?

Comment: Why is this marked as convex optimization? It certainly is not convex.

Comment: I am sorry about this. I deleted the tag. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @nam: It would be nice to get some feedback on the answer I provided (the bounty you offered expires tomorrow). I think it provides the closed-form solution you were looking for. Is it useful to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a nice closed-form expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf X^{(i)}}$, however, I can tell you how you can get to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf x^{(i)}}$, where $\mathbf x^{(i)} = {\rm vec}\{\mathbf X^{(i)}\}$. From there, the desired $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf X^{(i)}}$ is just a reshape.

Essentially, it relies on five ingredients:

1. $\|\mathbf X\|_{\rm F}^2 = \|{\rm vec}\{\mathbf X\}\|_2^2$
2. ${\rm vec}\{\mathbf A \mathbf X \mathbf B\} = (\mathbf B^{\rm T} \otimes \mathbf A)\cdot {\rm vec}\{\mathbf X\}$ where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product (which implies  ${\rm vec}\{\mathbf A \mathbf X \} = (\mathbf I \otimes \mathbf A)\cdot {\rm vec}\{\mathbf X\}$).
3. ${\rm vec}\{\mathbf X_1 \odot \mathbf X_2\} = ([\mathbf I_N \odot \mathbf X_1] \otimes \mathbf I_P)\cdot{\rm vec}\{\mathbf X_2\}$ where $\mathbf X_1$ is $M \times N$ and $\mathbf X_2$ is $P \times N$
4. ${\rm vec}\{\mathbf X_1 \odot \mathbf X_2\} = [\mathbf I_{MN} \odot (\mathbf X_2\cdot [\mathbf I_N \otimes \mathbf 1_{1\times M}])]\cdot{\rm vec}\{\mathbf X_1\}$ where $\mathbf X_1$ is $M \times N$ and $\mathbf X_2$ is $P \times N$
5. $\frac{\partial \|\mathbf b - \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{x}\|_2^2}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = 2\mathbf{A}^{\rm T}(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{x}-\mathbf b)$

For the proofs:

1. is trivial, both are the sum of all elements squared.
2. can be found in many textbooks and is not hard to show either, cf., e.g., [*]
3. when I needed it I didn't find a proof anywhere so I proved it myself. If you don't mind, I'd like to give my [dissertation](http://theses.eurasip.org/theses/473/advanced-algebraic-concepts-for-efficient-multi/download/) as a reference where it is Proposition 3.1.2, the proof is in Appendix B.2. There might be textbooks that contain something similar.
4. see 3., covered by the same proposition. This may not be the shortest form but it works.
5. is again straightforward: $\|\mathbf b - \mathbf A \mathbf x\|_2^2 = (\mathbf b^{\rm T} - \mathbf x^{\rm T} \mathbf{A}^T) (\mathbf b - \mathbf{A}  \mathbf{x})$, then use the product rule.

Now let us put everything together:

$$
   f   = \left\|\mathbf B - \mathbf A \left( \mathbf X^{(1)} \odot \mathbf X^{(2)} \right) \right\|_{\rm F}^2 \\
      = \left\| \mathbf b - \left(\mathbf I_3 \otimes \mathbf{A}\right) {\rm vec}\{\mathbf X^{(1)} \odot \mathbf X^{(2)}\} \right\|_2^2 \\
 = \left\| \mathbf b - \mathbf C_1 \cdot{\rm vec}\{\mathbf X_1\} \right\|_2^2 \\
= \left\| \mathbf b - \mathbf C_2 \cdot{\rm vec}\{\mathbf X_2\} \right\|_2^2 \\
$$

where $\mathbf b = {\rm vec}\{\mathbf B\}$, $\mathbf C_1 = \left(\mathbf I_3 \otimes \mathbf{A}\right) \cdot [\mathbf I_{27} \odot (\mathbf X_2\cdot [\mathbf I_3 \otimes \mathbf 1_{1\times 9}])]$ and $\mathbf C_2 = \left(\mathbf I_3 \otimes \mathbf{A}\right) \cdot([\mathbf I_3 \odot \mathbf X_1] \otimes \mathbf I_4)$. The first step uses 1.+2., the third and fourth line use 3. and 4., respectively.

Finally, using 5. we then have

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf x^{(i)}} = 2 \mathbf C_i^{\rm T}(\mathbf C_i\mathbf x^{(i)} - \mathbf b)$$

for $i=1, 2$ with $\mathbf C_i$ given above. From this expression, the matrix derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf X^{(i)}}$ you wanted is given by reshaping $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf x^{(i)}}$ back into a matrix of appropriate size.

[*] H. Neudecker, “Some theorems on matrix differentiation with special reference to Kronecker matrix products,” Journal of the American Statistical Association, vol. 64, pp. 953–963, 1969.

**edit**: Since I did a quick test in Matlab to verify it, I thought I might share this bit as well (it uses a function `krp` to calculate the Khatri-Rao product):

```
B = randn(100,3);
A = randn(100,36);
X1 = randn(9,3);
X2 = randn(4,3);
f = norm(B - A*krp(X1,X2),'fro')^2;
C1 = kron(eye(3),A)*krp(eye(27),X2*kron(eye(3),ones(1,9)));
C2 = kron(eye(3),A)*kron(krp(eye(3),X1),eye(4));
disp(f - norm(B(:)-C1*X1(:))^2)   % it is zero
disp(f - norm(B(:)-C2*X2(:))^2)   % it is zero
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but may I know how to verify the desired gradient is $2C_{i}^{T}(C_{i} x^{(i)}-b)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by verify: I gave the proof, you can follow each step. If you need more details in any of the steps let me know, I'll gladly provide it.

Comment: Thanks again. May I have a follow-up question: What if the objective function becomes $f = \| B - A(X^{(1)}\odot X^{(2)} \odot X^{(3)})\|$ and I would like to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X^{(i)}}$?

Comment: The tools I provided allow you to extend it to this case as well. let $Y = X^{(2)} \odot X^{(3)}$. Then you can directly apply my answer to get the gradient wrt. $X^{(1)}$. Also, you can get the vectorized version with respect to $Y$ àla $\|b - \tilde{C} \cdot {\rm vec}\{{Y}\}\| = \|b - \tilde{C} \cdot {\rm vec}\{{X^{(2)} \odot X^{(3)}}\}\|$. Then, to extract either $X^{(2)}$ or $X^{(3)}$, apply rule number 3 and 4, respectively, once more to get $\|b - \tilde{C} \cdot (\ldots) \cdot {\rm vec}\{X^{(2)}\}\|$ and $\|b - \tilde{C} \cdot (\ldots) \cdot {\rm vec}\{X^{(3)}\}\|$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\p{\partial} \def\bb{\mathbb}$
Given two matrices with the same number of columns, e.g.
$$A\in{\bb R}^{a\times n} \qquad B\in{\bb R}^{b\times n}$$
their Khatri-Rao $(\boxtimes)$ product can be written in terms of the Kronecker $(\otimes)$ and Hadamard $(\odot)$ products and all-ones vectors ${\tt1}_p\in{\bb R}^{p}\;$
$$\eqalign{
A\boxtimes B &= (A\otimes {\tt1}_b)\odot({\tt1}_a\otimes B) \\
}$$
We'll also need one more product, the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:C &= {\rm Tr}(A^TC)\qquad &\big({\rm for}\;\, C\in{\bb R}^{a\times n}\big) \\
A:C &= C:A \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F &\big({\rm useful\,identity}\big) \\
A:(C\odot M) &= (A\odot C):M &\big({\rm also\,useful}\big) \\
}$$

Since this derivation is going to be complicated enough without the distraction of superscripts, let's define the following matrices for ease of typing
$$\eqalign{
X &= X^{(1)}\in{\bb R}^{9\times 3}\qquad &Y = X^{(2)}\in{\bb R}^{4\times 3} \\
Z &= X\boxtimes Y\in{\bb R}^{36\times 3}\qquad &W = A^T(AZ-B)\in{\bb R}^{36\times 3} \\
w &= {\rm vec}(W)\qquad &{\cal W} = {\rm Diag}(w)\in{\bb R}^{108\times 108} \\
}$$
Write the objective function in terms of these variables
then calculate the differential.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \tfrac 12(AZ-B):(AZ-B) \\
df &= (AZ-B):(A\,dZ) \\
 &= W:dZ \\
 &= W:(dX\boxtimes Y) + W:(X\boxtimes dY) \\
}$$
Now calculate the gradient with respect to $X$.
$$\eqalign{
df &= W:(dX\boxtimes Y) \\
 &= W:(dX\otimes{\tt1}_4)\odot({\tt1}_9\otimes Y) \\
 &= W\odot({\tt1}_9\otimes Y):(dX\otimes{\tt1}_4) \\
 &= w\odot{\rm vec}({\tt1}_9\otimes Y):{\rm vec}(dX\otimes{\tt1}_4) \\
 &= {\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}({\tt1}_9\otimes Y):{\rm vec}(dX\otimes{\tt1}_4) \\
 &= {\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}({\tt1}_9\otimes Y)
  :(I_{27}\otimes{\tt1}_4)\cdot{\rm vec}(dX) \\
 &= (I_{27}\otimes{\tt1}_4^T)\cdot{\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}({\tt1}_9\otimes Y):dx \\
\frac{\p f}{\p x}
 &= (I_{27}\otimes{\tt1}_4^T)\cdot{\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}({\tt1}_9\otimes Y) \\
}$$
And with respect to $Y$.
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= {\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}(X\otimes{\tt1}_4)
  :{\rm vec}({\tt1}_9\otimes dY) \\
 &= {\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}(X\otimes{\tt1}_4)
  :({\tt1}_9\otimes I_{12})\cdot{\rm vec}(dY) \\
 &= ({\tt1}_9^T\otimes I_{12})\cdot{\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}(X\otimes{\tt1}_4):dy \\
\frac{\p f}{\p y}
 &= ({\tt1}_9^T\otimes I_{12})\cdot{\cal W}\cdot{\rm vec}(X\otimes{\tt1}_4) \\
}$$
The gradients can be converted between vector and matrix forms, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\p f}{\p y} &= {\rm vec}\left(\frac{\p f}{\p Y}\right) 
\qquad\iff\qquad
\frac{\p f}{\p Y} &= {\rm unvec}\left(\frac{\p f}{\p y}\right) \\\\
}$$
These results are in a different form than Florian's,
but they should be equivalent.