# Solve $\min_{\mathbf{V}}~\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{U}\mathbf{V}\mathbf{X}\|_{F}^{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|\mathbf{V}\|_{F}^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, matrix-decomposition

I got a following optimization problem

$$\min_{\mathbf{V}}~\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{U}\mathbf{V}\mathbf{X}\|_{F}^{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|\mathbf{V}\|_{F}^{2}$$
where the matrices $\mathbf{Z}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times T}$, $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times R}$ ($\mathbf{U}^\top\mathbf{U}\neq\mathbf{I}_{R}$), $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{R}^{R\times M}$, and $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times T}$ ($\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\neq\mathbf{I}_{M}$).

Is there a closed-form solution to the variable $\mathbf{V}$? Thanks for your help in advance!

Note that I know there is a solution by using vectorization and Kronecker product (see [Differentiation wrt matrix involvoing Khatri-rao product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2154495/738418) on Math StackExchange):

$$\hat{\mathbf{V}}=\operatorname{arg}\min_{\mathbf{V}}~\frac{1}{2}\|\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{Z})-(\mathbf{X}^\top\otimes\mathbf{U})\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{V})\|_{2}^{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{V})\|_{2}^{2}$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

But in fact, I want to obtain a solution in the form of matrix.

Comment: Is there any structure of matrices like $U^T U = I$?

Comment: The gradient of the cost function w.r.t. $V$ can be computed as $-U^T(Z - U V X) X^T + \lambda V$, which can be set to zero. But I am not sure whether one can extract $V$ because of "sandwiching" of $V$ unless there is some structure of matrices like $U^T U = I$ or $XX^T = I$... Perhaps, linear algebra experts can help you.

Comment: Thank you! But I do not have any structure like $U^\top U=I$ or $XX^\top=I$.

Comment: If either $(U^TU)^{-1}$ or $(XX^T)^{-1}$ exist, then you can rearrange the gradient equation derived by @user550103 into a [Sylvester equation](https://nhigham.com/2020/09/01/what-is-the-sylvester-equation/) for which several good algorithms exist.

Comment: @greg Indeed, Sylvester equation is an option -- thank you so much. I was wondering if we can find a closed-form analytical solution as OP desired. So, it seems that one has to resort to iterative algorithms...